# Will this regex match "i.imgur.com/xxx"?

Tags: java, regex

Will this regex match `http://i.imgur.com/xxx`?

```
"http://i.imgur.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

I don't use regex really, and I have learned it once barely. I googled how to do it for imgur and every one had really long ones, isn't this good enough? it seems to be working but what will it miss and how to improve?

I want to find all i.imgur.com/xxx in order to download the imgur .jpg. Basically it MUST look like "http://i.imgur.com/" the rest is going to be either "afsidjf123" "Bdfsi13" "123aslefBA"

Comment: Every regular expression starts with the question *"what am I trying to match"*. You're not telling us that.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: To begin with, in regex `.` (dot) is a meta-character that matches any character so I suppose no would be the answer. What is it you are trying to match?

Comment: it says in my descript I want to find imgur, and the regex has i.imgur, sorry I thought this was descriptive enough. I want to find all i.imgur.com/xxx in order to download the imgur .jpg..@Boris the spider, what if I escape the "." with an "\". Basically it MUST look like "http://i.imgur.com/" the rest is going to be either "afsidjf123" "Bdfsi13" "123aslefBA"

Comment: To test regexes you can use tools like [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Comment: "it seems to be working but what will it miss and how to improve?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, **yes**.

Depending on the language you're using, that's one way of doing it.

Alternatively, you could use something simpler like `\w`, which matches all word characters:

```
http://i\\.imgur\\.com/\\w*
```

**Important too:** `.` is a special character in regular expressions used to match "any one character"; you could end up with some false positives using it the way you have. You'll need to escape literal periods with a backslash `\`.

See it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/tP0iU7

(Note the backslash-escaped `/`, a requirement for PHP, and in the expression above, `\` must be escaped by another `\`).

**Some things to note:**

- Since you're using Java, you'll need to **double escape** each backslash as well, as regular expressions in Java are just regular strings. Example updated to reflect this.
- Be aware that this expression won't match `.` in `image.jpg`; if you want to capture that too, you'll need to use a character class like `[\w.]` instead of just `\w`.
- Be aware that by specifying specifically `http://`, you won't ever match anything hosted over `https://`. You could make this match both by adding a "non-greedy" `s?` like so: `https?://`

Comment: thanks, I like the \w better.

Comment: @aaa for sure -- just be aware that it won't match `.` in `image.jpg`; if you want to capture that too, you'll need to use a character class like `[\w.]` instead of just `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to escape `.` as it's a special character in regex (meaning any character). This regex will match `http://i\.imgur\.com/` followed by any letters or numbers if that's what you want:

```
"http://i\.imgur\.com/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it says Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using java on windows

Comment: Also, use a **+** instead of a *. If a star is used it will match http : //i.imgur.com/